# Will I need more than one community if I want to hide Chatter posts from anonymous users?

Tags: community, chatter, permissions, customer-community

We are setting up a Salesforce Community, where the public will have access to certain articles as defined by data categories, and logged-in users will have access to additional articles and the ability to create/access Chatter Answers posts. However, we do not want anonymous users to have access to the Chatter posts/feeds.

We want to create just one community to handle this setup. According to [this answer](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hfolAAA), you cannot hide certain posts/feeds from other logged in users, but is it possible to hide all posts/feeds from anonymous users? If not now (Winter 16), will it be possible with the Spring 16 release?